# Unable to run Spring Boot with Kotlin project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, kotlin

I have `Eclipse Photon` with `Kotlin plugin for Eclipse 0.8.6` and `Spring Tools 3.9.5.RELEASE` plugins installed. I followed [these](https://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v373/SpringToolSuiteAndKotlin.html) instructions and created a new project with wizard:

[image]

Then I created a new `Run Configuration` and edited the main class as instructed in the reference:

[image]

After running project, I got this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.kotlinexample.KotlinExampleApplicationKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.kotlinexample.KotlinExampleApplicationKt
```

I've checked my `build.gradle` with [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/) documentation and it seems OK:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.51'
        springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.kotlinexample'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: And your Kotlin source?

Comment: `Kotlin plugin for Eclipse 0.8.6`

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to create a Maven project instead of Gradle.
2. Install the Eclipse Kotlin Plugin
3. Install the latest AspectJ Development Tools plugin
4. Choose the JDK version by going to Preferences, and make this settings:

> Preferences => Kotlin +> Compiler => JVM target version = 1.8

> Preferences => Kotlin +> Compiler => JDK Home = path_to_your_jdk_installation

5. Add the Kotlin **open** keyword before the Main class declaration as the example bellow:

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class KotlinExampleApplication { ... }
```

5. Compile your project with maven (mvn clean install)
6. Run it by the Spring dashboard as you did

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but I faced the same issue. Right clicking the project and do **Configure Kotlin** then **Add Kotlin Nature** did the work for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).